# How to transfer an excel spreadsheet to an access database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm making a program to track my weight, calories I eat in a day, and the date, to help me lose weight. I'm manually putting in these values into a spreadsheet with those three columns (date, calories, weight). I want to transfer the information in these three columns into an access database.

Code so far:

```
Sub transferdata()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

connStr = "C:\Users\sachu\Desktop\Assignment 5\CalorieDatabase.mdb"
providerStr = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

    With cn
        .ConnectionString = connStr
        .Provider = providerStr
        .Open
    End With

rs.Open sqlStr, cn
rs.Close
cn.Close
End Sub
```

So far my code is only starting the connection between access and excel

Comment: Why aren't you putting it directly into the Access DB instead of using Excel? A data entry form is simple to create in Access. And did you try searching here for *[ado] insert into access from excel*? I see many results of that search that would get you started.

Comment: It's because I want to use Excel as the UI. I'll try searching that up thank you

Comment: Got it. *Because I insist on doing it the hard way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Let's look at a couple of case studies.

```
 Export data from Excel to Access (ADO)
```

If you want to export data to an Access table from an Excel worksheet, the macro example below shows how this can be done.

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb;"
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "TableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable  
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also . . .

```
 Export data from Excel to Access (DAO)
```

If you want to export data to an Access table from an Excel worksheet, the macro example below illustrates another way to do this.

```
Sub DAOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, r As Long
    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb") 
    ' open the database
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable) 
    ' get all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also . . .

```
Browse to a single EXCEL File and Import Data from that EXCEL File via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA)
```

Here's yet another way . . . 
    Sub TryThis()

```
        Dim strPathFile As String
        Dim strTable As String, strBrowseMsg As String
        Dim strFilter As String, strInitialDirectory As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = False

        strBrowseMsg = "Select the EXCEL file:"

        ' Change C:\MyFolder\ to the path for the folder where the Browse
        ' window is to start (the initial directory). If you want to start in
        ' ACCESS' default folder, delete C:\MyFolder\ from the code line,
        ' leaving an empty string as the value being set as the initial
        ' directory
        strInitialDirectory = "C:\MyFolder\"

        strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xls)", "*.xls")

        strPathFile = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:=strInitialDirectory, _
              Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=False, _
              DialogTitle:=strBrowseMsg, _
              Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

        If strPathFile = "" Then
              MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
              Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
              strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        ' Kill strPathFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this looks like a dead thread but I wanted to revive for Office 360 users. I had to compile an answer from several sources to make something workable. See below.

First- note that you need at least the 2 following references active in your Tools>References Menu.

Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library &
Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine Object

You may also need to have:
Visual Basic for Applications//
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library//
OLE Automation//
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library//
Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library//
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

```
Sub rtnExporttoAccess()
Dim oDAO As DAO.DBEngine, oDB As DAO.Database, oRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim oSelect As Range, sPath As String, sRecordSet As String
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheet") 'excel sheet
Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item("YourTable") 'excel table
Set oSelect = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range 'set your sheet and range however you want
sPath = "your database file path"

sRecordSet = "the title of the table in that database" 'access table
Set oDAO = New DAO.DBEngine
Set oDB = oDAO.OpenDatabase(sPath)
Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset(sRecordSet)

oRSct = oRS.Fields.Count
xclFieldCt = table.ListColumns.Count
If oRSct > xclFieldCt Then
    intTargetCt = oRSct
Else
    intTargetCt = xclFieldCt
End If

For i = 2 To oSelect.Rows.Count
    oRS.AddNew
'finds the correct fields to add data to
    For j = 0 To intTargetCt - 1    'access is base 0 so the end is always -1
          oRSHeaderName = oRS.Fields(j).Name 'gets database table variable header name
          For col = 1 To intTargetCt  'excel is base 1
                   lastRowHeaderName = table.HeaderRowRange(1, col) ' gets excel table variable header name
                   If oRSHeaderName = lastRowHeaderName Then  'this verifies both headers are the same
                       oRS.Fields(j) = Now
                       Exit For
                   End If
                   If oRSHeaderName = "Pass/Failed" And lastRowHeaderName = "Pass/Failed" Then 'this verifies the you are putting the data where you want it if headers arent the same.
                       oRS.Fields(j) = cbxPF
                       Exit For
                   End If
          Next col
    Next j
    oRS.Update
Next i
oDB.Close
End Sub
```

ASH's second DAO option is basically what this code is as well. I included the references and gave some extra options for you to see some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Creat a stand alone Acces DB then link the Excel in it. The Access has tools to import data from Excel with live communication.
Follow this:

1. Open MS Access
2. Creat new blank database (in this step you have to give name to the database, and set the save location)
3. In the new database on External Data tab choose the correct type to add based on what you want to import (in this case you have to select Excel)

   - in the earlier MS Access version the popular insertable things were stretched
   - in the 2016 version, and O365 the options is more compact so there is one option called New Data Source which contain all possibilities
4. The import progress consits of several steps.

   1. you have to select the source and set how you want to import data. You can import data into a new table in Access as a copy, or you can connect the source of data to the Access database. Select connect source data for live communication.
   2. select inner data source (for example which sheet, or range you want to import)
   3. set if the first row contain headers
   4. give a name to the linked table

Finally data from Excel linked into Access and it will update when you use it.

Comment: I'd upvote this if you add more detail on how to do it.